# Script that checks a URL for specific text

Tags: linux, bash, curl, monitoring

Looking for a bash script that will accomplish the followings:

1. Check a URL (ex. www.google.com)
2. Looks for a specific text string
3. if it exists, it does nothing
4. if it doesnt, then sends out an email to alert someone

I tried the following script, it doesnt do anything, I dont get any email or anything.

```
#!/bin/sh
URL="URL"
TMPFILE=`mktemp /string_watch.XXXXXX`
curl -s -o ${TMPFILE} ${URL} 2>/dev/null
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ];
then
echo "Unable to connect to ${URL}"
exit 2
fi
RES=`grep -i "StringToLookFor" ${TMPFILE}`
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ];
then
echo "String not found in ${URL}" | mail -s "Alert" your@email
exit 1
fi
echo "String found"
exit 0;
```

Comment: What happens if you just enter `mail -s "Alert" your@email` at the command line? Do you get an email?

Comment: @JimGarrison The script just hangs in there, I am forced to close/stop it.

Comment: No, what happens if you run `mail -s "Alert" your@email` at the command line, outside of your script?

Comment: @JimGarrison it hangs again, nothing happens, I am forced to hit ctrl+C

Comment: add set -x to see what is going on. does mail command work if you do it online ?

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
mail -s "Alert" your@email
```

is pausing to let you enter the text of your email.  If you want to send an email with the indicated subject and no text you need to do

```
mail -s "Alert" your@email < /dev/null
```

Comment: Jim, that did solve the issue of hanging, however, I still do not get any emails.

Comment: Then you have mail server configuration issues, which are off-topic for SO.  You need to resolve how to send email successfully from the command line first.  I suggest you post that question at [su]